# mu4e-headers view: move point to first unread e-mail

Tags: mu4e

I am using `mu4e-headers` view with emails sorted by date in ascending order: the most recently received e-mail is shown on the bottom.

I usually have 20-30 older, read mails in my inbox, with the oldest one on top of the buffer. When I open the `mu4e-headers` buffer, then point is at the first buffer line, and therefore at my "oldest" e-mail. I would prefer the following behavior:

1. When the `mu4e-headers` buffer is opened, then point is automatically moved to (the beginning of) the line of the first *unread* email
2. If possible, point is at the same time in the first row of the frame. That is, the buffer is scrolled down, such that initially only the new, unread e-mails are visible, and I have to scroll up to see older ones.

Achieving only 1. would already help me a lot, if 2. turns out to be too difficult. I would appreciate any advice on how to achieve this.

My Elisp programming skills are rather low, but I think I have already figured out that `mu4e-headers-mode-hook` is the right place where a function that implements the above can be hooked in. But I have no idea how to identify the line of the first unread message, and how to move the cursor there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mu4e-headers-find-if` function moves to the next header for which FUNC returns non-nil, so to address point 1 we have to check if the message has an `unread` flag. The last line addresses point 2 but let me know if it doesn't.

```el
(add-hook 'mu4e-headers-found-hook
          (lambda ()
            (mu4e-headers-find-if
             (lambda (msg)
               (let ((flags (mu4e-message-field msg :flags)))
                 (member 'unread flags))))
            (when (get-buffer-window mu4e~headers-buffer-name)
              (switch-to-buffer mu4e~headers-buffer-name))
            (recenter 0)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With recent mu4e, `mu4e~headers-buffer-name` should be `mu4e-headers-buffer-name`